# search & replace on 3000 row, 25 column spreadsheet

Tags: php, mysql, database, large-files, spreadsheet

I'm attempting to clean up data in this (old) spreadsheet and need to remove things like single and double quotes, HTML tags and so on. Trouble is, it's a 3000 row file with 25 columns and every spreadsheet app I've tried (NeoOffice, MS Excel, Apple Numbers) chokes on it. Hard.

Any ideas on how else I can clean this thing up for import to MySQL? Clearly I could go through each record manually, row by row, but would like to avoid that if at all possible. Likewise, I could write a PHP script to handle it on import, but don't want to put the server into a death spiral either.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution:
Exported the spreadsheet as CSV, and with my desktop running PHP and MySQL I imported the csv file into MySQL using the "LOAD DATA" SQL command, and then used PHP + MySQL to clean up each row.
Much, much faster than asking a desktop app like Excel or Numbers to do a find & replace.

Answer (score 0):

If it's in Excel format, you might try to access it through python.

http://www.python-excel.org/

I've never done this myself, but it might work in your case.